# Can the partial order of S induce a parital order on Y?

Tags: order-theory

The problem comes from an article: Order Structure on the algebra of permutations and of planar bianry trees. I will describe the problem independently here.

## Question

Suppose $(S, \leq)$ is a partially ordered set and Y is a set. There is a surjective map $\Psi: S \longrightarrow Y$ such that $\forall t\in Y$, $\Psi^{-1}(t)$ is an interval, that is, $\exists Min(t),Max(t)\in S$,

$\Psi^{-1}(t) = \{ \sigma\in S | Min(t) \leq \sigma \leq Max(t) \}$.

Then how can the partial order of S induce a partial order of Y such that $\forall \sigma,\tau\in S$, $\sigma \leq \tau \Longrightarrow \Psi(\sigma) \leq \Psi(\tau)$?

## My Idea

I try to define the partial order of Y as the transitive closure of

$\{ w \leq_B t \big| Min(w) \leq Max(t)  \}$

But this is not right. I can not verify the asymmetric axiom.

Comment: The order on $Y$ is $x \le y$ if and only if $\exists \sigma, \tau \in S$ with $\sigma \le \tau$ and $x = \Psi(\sigma), y=\Psi(\tau)$. You will have to consider what is says about some $\alpha, \beta \in S$ if $\alpha$ is not comparable to $\beta$, but $\Psi(\alpha)$ is comparable to $\Psi(\beta)$. (It is possible - you need to figure out how. This will help you to show the P.O. axioms for $Y$.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the mistakes.  And I think usually this will not induce a well-defined parital order. But in the article, things are special.

Comment: Under the interval condition given in the problem, it will.